# Ansible Automation Platform 2.2.1 fails with "system hostname cannot be localhost"

Tags: ansible

I keep running into the following error while installing Ansible Automation Platform 2.2:

> TASK [ansible.automation_platform_installer.preflight : Ensure hostname on nodes with receptor installed is not localhost] ***
> fatal: [172.16.10.13]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "The system hostname cannot be localhost, receptor requires it to be set to something other than localhost"}

The inventory file contents:

```yaml
[automationcontroller]
172.16.10.13

[automationcontroller:vars]
peers=execution_nodes
ansible_user=root
ansible_ssh_private_key_file="path to my key file"
```

Example inventory file from Red Hat installation guide:

```yaml
[automationcontroller]
127.0.0.1 ansible_connection=local


[database]
database.example.com

[all:vars]
admin_password='<password>'
pg_password='<password>'

pg_host='database.example.com'
pg_port='5432'

pg_database='awx'
pg_username='awx'

registry_url='registry.redhat.io'
registry_username='<registry username>'
registry_password='<registry password>'
```

Installation with both fails with the same error.

Comment: You should post the role/playbook you are using because, maybe you defined somewhere the hostname.

Comment: It's the Ansible Automation Platform setup:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_ansible_automation_platform/2.0-ea/html-single/red_hat_ansible_automation_platform_installation_guide/index#planning-installation

Comment: Thats weird, maybe you can try to add to your host: ansible_connection=ssh

Comment: I've also tried that with no success. I believe the default connection is ssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic networking topology in an ip4 system consists of the total ip4 address space less certain specific adress blocks and individual addresses.

The localhost/localnet block at 127.n.n.n is routable, but only to other addresses in that block, *none of which are routable beyond the confines of the local host environment*.

Hence the name ‘localhost’.

Since it is impossible to network on an address space that is unrouteable to any network, i.e., literally any other host, you will find it a prerequisite activity to fully configure a proper network in which all collaborative network contributors are all routable with each other.

Comment: I don't completely understand the point that you are trying to make.

Comment: Simply that  you can’t expect to install a networked application of any kind on 127.n.n.n and expect that application to be able to cooperate with any other application running on a different host.

Comment: My question could have been weirdly phrased but what I am trying to do is install Ansible Automation Platform on localhost as described in the documentation: 
https://access.redhat.com/webassets/avalon/j/includes/session/scribe/?redirectTo=https%3A%2F%2Faccess.redhat.com%2Fdocumentation%2Fen-us%2Fred_hat_ansible_automation_platform%2F2.0-ea%2Fhtml-single%2Fred_hat_ansible_automation_platform_installation_guide%2Findex%23planning-installation
That shouldn't be interacting with any other hosts.

Comment: I think your question was fine, nothing weird there - but your faith in redhat documentation may be too high. To me, if it’s configured for localhost, and the software then crashes with an error concerning that configuration, then the configuration must be the source of the fault, without respect to what application that may be.

Comment: Starting to think you might be right 

Comment: I might still be wrong too - but the logic I’m following is fairly solid.  My best advice is don’t give up, and don’t be afraid to try some variations on that configuration.

Comment: The solution you added confirms that my answer is correct. It would be awesome if you could do the appropriate things to reflect that state of affairs 

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are supposed to use the fqdn.
On rhel 9:

> sudo hostname your-hostname

```yaml
[automationcontroller]
your-hostname.example.com

[automationcontroller:vars]
peers=execution_nodes
ansible_user=root
ansible_ssh_private_key_file="path to my key file"
```